# FileUpload Causes Page Cannot Display

Tags: .net, file-upload, iis-6

I am using File Upload control to upload a file to web server and then insert it into database. I am able to send big files around 7 MB in my development environment which has a single web server.

However, when I deploy the same site in another environment which has load balanced servers, I am unable to upload the big files. I am able to upload files upto 5 MB in this environment, but 7MB file fails to upload.

The execution timeout and maxRequestLength are set to high values in web.config and the same is available in both environments.

In IE, I get the error as "The page cannot be displayed."

In Firefox, I get the error as "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

Please advice what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered problems with IIS application pools restarting in the past.  Go to app pool hosting your web application, then open up the advanced settings:

[image]

Disable Ping Enabled or try increasing the Ping Maximum Response Time

Answer (score 0):

I realise that you've already tried increasing your `maxRequestLength` value, however are you aware it's measured in kilobytes (KB)? (Also, for others that are visiting this question, may not know about this setting). The default is 4096KB (4 MB).

I set mine to 10MB to fix my issue: `<system.web><httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" /></system.web>`.

More information is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx).

---

Regarding your load-balancer, I wonder if you could use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what the problem might be. Also, could the load-balancer itself have a maximum upload size?